# Find occurence of a term in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, autocomplete, autosuggest

> I am using ***elastic search for autosuggest*** in ***JAVA*** and need to store the terms and their occurences in the index.While indexing products , a particular string can be indexed multiple times.To avoid that , in case it is already stored we have to update occurence of the indexed term.
>   ELastic Search POJO:

```
@Document(indexName = "autosuggest", type = "autosuggest")
public class Autosuggest {

@Id
@Field(pattern ="id")
private String id;

@Field(pattern ="completion")
private Completion completion;

@Field(pattern ="occurence")
private Integer occurence;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public Completion getCompletion() {
    return completion;
}

public void setCompletion(Completion completion) {
    this.completion = completion;
}

public Integer getOccurence() {
    return occurence;
}

public void setOccurence(Integer occurence) {
    this.occurence = occurence;
}

}
```

> Completion object

```
public class Completion {

private List<String> input;
private Integer weight;

public List<String> getInput() {
    return input;
}
public void setInput(List<String> input) {
    this.input = input;
}
public Integer getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
public Completion(List<String> input, Integer weight) {
    super();
    this.input = input;
    this.weight = weight;
}
}
```

> Sample object in elastic search

```
  {
    "_index" : "autosuggest",
    "_type" : "autosuggest",
    "_id" : "BUj0zGUBr5AQqSH41l0m",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "completion" : {
        "input" : [
          "Casual Shirts for Men"
        ],
        "weight" : 2
      },
      "occurence" : 1
    }
  }
```

> How can I update the occurence if the term is already indexed in elastic search?

Comment: Hi Priancy, you can validate data before indexing it. Check whether its available in indexing or not. if Yes, then you can update/ replace entire document with your incremented occurrence.

Comment: @PKhode Used this query : curl -X GET "localhost:9200/autosuggest/autosuggest/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"size": 0,
  "query": {"match": {
  "input": "Casual Shirts for Men"
}}}'  and got {"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}. It is not  returning the exact document

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer since I can't post a comment.

@Priancy: The query you have used seems to be incorrect. Please find the correct query below. I have tested this query with the sample object you have provided in the question.

```
"query": {
    "match": {
      "completion.input": "Casual Shirts for Men"
    }
}
```

---

Please also go through [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/incrementing-an-integer-field/6643) link on how you can skip this approach and increment the occurrence.

Thanks

Comment: This gives a parsing exception : {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]","line":2,"col":1}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]","line":2,"col":1}

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? I had run the query on my system before posting it here. Also, the query you have posted as an answer will match(read query) all the fields under 'completion'. So it might give you the wrong results if there are more than one field of type text.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  "query": {
     "match": {
         "completion": "Casual Shirts for Men"
      }
  }
```